# change values in last two lists of lists

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a solution to change the last two lists in a list of lists. The number of lists inside the list is variable. The change of the values depends on every time the last two lists.

```
list_of_colors=[['red','red','red','red'],['red','red','red','red'],
               ['red','red','red','red'], ['red','red','red','red']]
```

I expect the second to the last list changes completely from `'red'` to `'lightgrey'` and in the last list, only the last two from `'red'` into `'lightgrey'` - like this:

```
list_of_colors=[['red','red','red','red'],['red','red','red','red'],
               ['lightgrey','lightgrey','lightgrey','lightgrey'], ['red','red','lightgrey','lightgrey']]
```

This list of lists is to color a plotly table - Thanks for the help

Comment: i changed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more dynamic solution, i.e. in case the lists don't have a fixed length, you can try this:

```
list_of_colors[-2] = ['lightgrey'] * len(list_of_colors[-2])

last_n = 2

list_of_colors[-1][-last_n:] = ['lightgrey'] * last_n
```

In the `last_n` variable, I have specified the number of elements you wish to change, of the last list.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, the parent list which contains the lists can have variable number of lists inside it, and you specifically know what values you require inside the last two lists, Then, this should work:

```
list_of_colors[-1] = ['lightgrey','lightgrey','lightgrey','lightgrey']
list_of_colors[-2] = ['red','red','lightgrey','lightgrey']
```

Comment: Thank you shivam roy

Comment: the logic of plotly is different, so i opend a new Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248225/change-specific-positon-in-lists-of-lists 
may i its something for you