# change specific positon in lists of lists

Tags: python

I am looking for a solution to change specific position in all lists in an of lists. The number of lists inside the list is variable. The change of the values depends on every time at the same position. in my case the third, where I expect to change "red" to "lightgrey". the lists are filled only whit strings.

```
list_of_colors=[['red','red','red','red'],['red','red','red','red'],
               ['red','red','red','red'], ['red','red','red','red']]
```

i expect:

```
list_of_colors =[['red','red','lightgrey','red'],['red','red','lightgrey','red'],
               ['red','red','lightgrey','red'], ['red','red','lightgrey','red']]
```

This list of lists is to color a plotly table - Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you considered numpy. you can do this faster.

Comment: no, but would be a solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
def change_color(lists, new_color, position):
    for list_ in lists:
        list_[position-1] = new_color
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic way of solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

this could help you to give an idea:

```
list_of_colors=[['red','red','red','red'],['red','red','red','red'],
                       ['red','red','red','red'], ['red','red','red','red']]
new_color = "lightgrey"
position = 3
for list in  range(len(list_of_colors)):
    list_of_colors[list][position-1] = new_color
```

Comment: same as for the other answer using `range(len(<list>))` instead of `for <sublist> in <list>` or `for idx, <sublist> in enumarate(<list>)`

Answer (score -1):

```
list_of_colors=[['red','red','red','red'],['red','red','red','red'],
               ['red','red','red','red'], ['red','red','red','red']]

for i in range(len(list_of_colors)):
    list_of_colors[i][2]='lightgrey'
print(list_of_colors)
```

you can try this way using for loop for iterating over index of outer list and fix the position which you want to change in inner loop

Comment: Why do you need the index? Just iterate through the sublists: `for colors in list_of_colors`

Comment: he must be ex-java dev. I really dislike when people use `range(len(<list<))` as it's NEVER usefull in python. Either iterate on the list OR use enumerate if you need the index.